# How to: standard data in core data on "install"?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm working on an application which allows the user to create his own templates with controls. My question here is how I can populate some standard data in my core data database so the user can create his own templates beginning from a standard.

I heard this can be done using local json (there will be a backend using Json to communicate with the frontend), but  couldn't find a good tutorial how to do this...

Is there anyone who could help me with this, or is there anyone who has some better ideas to populate this standard data?

I'm using sql script now to populate my data now, but it's not a solution from the moment you install it on an iPad.

### Update

I'm willing to create standard entries in my database, so there are some standard controls on the standard template (with template, I mean the controls on a form defined by the user). To be something more specific, how can I parse local json to my core data database?

Comment: You need to clarify your question - what kind of `template`? What data type you want to use to store your `standard template`? Why 'it's not a solution' to use script once when application installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JSON is an option.

Simply transfer the JSON into a Foundation object, like this

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *dataArray =     
   [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

Now iterate through your new JSON object (an array in this case, but could be a dictionary) and populate your Core Data store one by one with

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" 
    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

and save.